# Validating form field for a specific combination of numbers and alphabets

Tags: regex, validation, sample, alphabet

I need to validate a form field for a specific type of combination of numbers and alphabets:

- first four digits are alphabets
- next digit is zero
- next 6 digits are numeric

e.g.
IBKL 0 001084

Comment: So what is the problem you have? Are you asking somebody to write an entire form validation function for you, or do you just need help with a quick regex for your field? `/^[A-Z]{4} 0 \d{6}$/` (By the way, "alphabet" doesn't mean what you think it means. You mean "letter".)

Comment: Don't know what exactly you want, but the regex is /[a-zA-Z]{4} 0 [0-9]{6}/ and you can use test method to test your input value

Comment: You need to define what letters (“alphabets”) you wish to allow (e.g., is “b” OK? “α”? “þ”?) and whether spaces are allowed and where – the example suggests that they are, but exactly how? The rest is simple, just writing it as a JavaScript regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your validation is client-side:

> first four digits are alphabets next digit is zero and next 6 digits are numeric

Compact test:

```
/[a-zA-Z]{4}\s?0\s?[0-9]{6}\s?$/.test("IBKL 0 001084 ");
/[a-zA-Z]{4}\s?0\s?[0-9]{6}\s?$/.test("IBKL 0 001084");
/[a-zA-Z]{4}\s?0\s?[0-9]{6}\s?$/.test("IBKL0001084");
```

Verbose test:

```
var first_four = "[a-zA-Z]{4}",  zero = "0",  next_six = "[0-9]{6}", space_maybe = "\\s?", end = "$";

RegExp(first_four + space_maybe + zero + space_maybe + next_six + space_maybe + end).test("IBKL 0 001084 ");

RegExp(first_four + space_maybe + zero + space_maybe + next_six + space_maybe + end).test("IBKL 0 001084");

RegExp(first_four + space_maybe + zero + space_maybe + next_six + space_maybe + end).test("IBKL0001084");
```